# How did the Colossal Titan manage to take the ODM gear off of someone while in titan form?

Tags: attack-on-titan

> In Season 2 episode 7, Bertolt,

in his titan form, is at surface level (apparently). But with that, he was still able to take the ODM gear off of someone through the mouth somehow. How did he do this?

I don't think it would work because there is too much to go through. There are meters of flesh between the back of the Colossal Titan's mouth and

> Bertolt.

The way Mikasa took out the Armored Titan with a thunder spear wouldn't work with the Colossal Titan. There is too much flesh to penetrate through.

So how did this character reach out and kill and or take the ODM gear?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide the episode or manga issue that the event you're concerned about too place in.

Comment: @Jontia fixed it